# do_compile: oe_runmake failed and do_compile: Function failed: do_compile error while building yocto project

Tags: yocto

I am new to yocto project and start to build yocto project by the steps provided in below link:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5.1/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html

I am getting errors when i give **$ bitbake core-image-sato** command. Detailed screenshots of errors are attached.

[error_screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaBA4.png)
[error_screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQv4P.png)

Below are the build logs for your reference.

================ Log Start ==================

```
lenovo@vvdn:~/bhavin/yocto/poky$ source oe-init-build-env

### Shell environment set up for builds. ###

You can now run 'bitbake <target>'

Common targets are:
    core-image-minimal
    core-image-sato
    meta-toolchain
    meta-ide-support

You can also run generated qemu images with a command like 'runqemu qemux86'
lenovo@vvdn:~/bhavin/yocto/poky/build$ 
lenovo@vvdn:~/bhavin/yocto/poky/build$ 
lenovo@vvdn:~/bhavin/yocto/poky/build$ bitbake core-image-sato
Loading cache: 100% |###########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1282 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.37.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "i586-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m32 i586"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "my-yocto-2.5:da3625c52e1ab8985fba4fc3d133edf92142f182"

Initialising tasks: 100% |######################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:07
Checking sstate mirror object availability: 100% |##############################################################################| Time: 0:20:32
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: qemu-native-2.11.1-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: qemu-native-2.11.1-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.7408)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.7408
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4 LD=ld  AR=ar OBJCOPY=objcopy LDFLAGS=-L/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -L/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -fuse-ld=bfd
|   GEN     ui/input-keymap-linux-to-qcode.c
|   GEN     ui/input-keymap-qcode-to-qnum.c
| make[1]: '/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/build/capstone/libcapstone.a' is up to date.
|   GEN     ui/input-keymap-qnum-to-qcode.c
| Traceback (most recent call last):
| Traceback (most recent call last):
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/qemu-2.11.1/ui/keycodemapdb/tools/keymap-gen", line 15, in <module>
|   File "/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/qemu-2.11.1/ui/keycodemapdb/tools/keymap-gen", line 15, in <module>
|         import csv
| import csv
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 7, in <module>
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 7, in <module>
|   File "/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/qemu-2.11.1/ui/keycodemapdb/tools/keymap-gen", line 15, in <module>
|     import csv
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 7, in <module>
|     from functools import reduce
|     from functools import reduce
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 10, in <module>
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 10, in <module>
|     from functools import reduce
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 10, in <module>
|     from _functools import partial, reduce
| ImportError: No module named _functools
|         from _functools import partial, reduce
| from _functools import partial, reduce
| ImportErrorImportError: : No module named _functoolsNo module named _functools
| 
|   CC      ui/vnc-enc-hextile.o
|   CC      ui/input-keymap.o
|   CC      ui/vnc-palette.o
|   CC      ui/vnc-enc-tight.o
|   CC      ui/vnc-enc-zrle.o
| /home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/qemu-2.11.1/ui/input-keymap.c:8:44: fatal error: ui/input-keymap-linux-to-qcode.c: No such file or directory
| compilation terminated.
| /home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/qemu-2.11.1/rules.mak:66: recipe for target 'ui/input-keymap.o' failed
| make: *** [ui/input-keymap.o] Error 1
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.11.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.7408)
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/qemu/qemu_2.11.1.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 830 tasks of which 817 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:/home/lenovo/bhavin/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/qemu/qemu_2.11.1.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
lenovo@vvdn:~/bhavin/yocto/poky/build$ 
lenovo@vvdn:~/bhavin/yocto/poky/build$
```

================ Log End ==================

Can anyone help me to solve these errors.Any help in this will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Bhavin Maru

Comment: Share logs as text or with pastebin like option.

Comment: Hi Parthiban,
Thanks for your reply i have added build logs for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like qemu did not get all its required modules.
Could you please try

```
bitbake qemu -c cleanall; bitbake qemu -f
```

Try its make any difference.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with qemu-native_4.1.0.bb:do_compile fialing. @Vysakh A V solution made no difference.